# Checking User Password, Always Returns False?

Tags: php, post, passwords

Before going through with updating a customer's subscription cancellation in Stripe, I ask for their password for confirmation. The password is hashed as sha1 when it's stored (obviously I never see it), so the password sent gets hashed and then they get compared. Here's the basic code I'm using, which gets submitted by a jQuery AJAX event:

```
$password = sha1( $_POST['password'] );
// get $stored_password from the DB using PDO.
if ( $stored_password != $password )
{
    die( 'Password is incorrect.' );
}
```

All other stuff that gets pulled from the DB entry matches the user (unique ID, name, email, &c.). The only thing that won't work is the password, even though both hashed strings are identical.

EDIT: I can echo both the submitted password and the stored password hashes to the page, and they're identical. I strip tags and trim all user input, both before they set the password the first time and when I run this check.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` not `sha1()`

Comment: Are you sure your table cell in database is long enough? It might get trimmed otherwise, a common mistake. Also, do not use sha1, that's what password_hash() is for

Comment: agree to use password_hash() instead. However it doesn't explain the problem. Can you post the sha1 from your db and the sha1 from your password hash input?

Comment: @JoshWoodcock @ MichałSkrzypek Yep, cell was long enough (no cropping) and both hashes matched. I'll re-do with password_hash instead and see if it resolves.

Comment: that will not fix the problem there is some other logic issue

Comment: You should post a `var_dump()` of both values (and the sent-in password...), perhaps it's simply some white-space surrounding a value. How are you storing the value?